# How are Google API quotas calculated?

Tags: api, python-requests, google-places-api, quota

So I'm making an app which uses Google Places API and I'mconfused at what are they trying to tell me with these quotas.

[image: Google APIs]

I'm using just 1 API key for this one API (places) and currently it shows I have around 600 requests done, which fits, but then this thing makes no sense. Why do I have limit 1 request per second yet it lets me make much more? And how come I have peak usage per 100 seconds just 4 when I'm sure I sent bulk requests which contained at least 20 in a row.

Comment: Does any of this https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/limits-quotas help?

Comment: @SiKing I don't think that applies to the API I'm using (Places API)